# Javascript: Acceptable way to referencing `this` from given two snippets

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var me = null;
var testFn = (function() {
    me = this;
    return {
        me1: me,
        fn1 : function() {
           me = this;
             return {   
                    me2 : me,
                    fn2 : function() {
                        me = this;
                        return {
                            me3: me
                        }
                    }
                }        
        }
    }
})();
```

**OR:**

```
var testFn = (function() {
    var me = this;
    return {
        me1: me,
        fn1 : function() {
           var me = this;
             return {   
                    me2 : me,
                    fn2 : function() {
                        var me = this;
                        return {
                            me3: me
                        }
                    }
                }        
        }
    }
})();
```

Between two segments given above, which one is best way to referencing `this`. Is there any other way best, please suggest.

Thanks.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using the second approach because me is declared inside a closure so iot doesn't pollute context where it is not needed. It is also clearer to which context me belongs too.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the second one, as it is destroyed when the `this` is, which makes more sense (they're in the same scope).

Not entirely related, but most people call the variable `that`: e.g. `var that = this;`

Comment: I wouldn't say most people do, self and _this are use a lot more than that from my experience.

Comment: I've seen `self` and `__self` used, but not `_this`. I guess it's mostly down to personal preference, though.